# Long run time for automorphic program

Tags: python, algorithm, math, time-complexity

I wrote a program to solve for the n<sup>th</sup> automorphic number (numbers that, when squared, end in the original number (ex. 625<sup>2</sup> = 390625, 390625 % 1000 = 625).

```
import time
def green(n):
  start_time = time.time()
  f = 3
  if n==1:
    return 1
  elif n==2:
    return 5
  elif n==3:
    return 6
  n1 = "5"
  n2 = "6"
  tempn2 = "0"
  tempn1 = "0"
  x = 1
  while f!=n+1:
    if int(n1) > int(n2):
      tempn2 = str(x) + n2
      while int(pow(int(tempn2), 2, 10**(len(tempn2)))) != int(tempn2):
        tempn2 = str(x) + n2
        x+=1
      x=1
      f+=1
      n2 = tempn2
      if f==n+1:
        break
    else:
      tempn1 = str(x) + n1
      while int(pow(int(tempn1), 2, 10**len(tempn1))) != int(tempn1):
        tempn1 = str(x) + n1
        x+=1
      x=1
      f+=1
      n1 = tempn1
  print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
  return min(int(n1), int(n2))
```

Sorry for the poor code, first year Comp Sci.

[Program Runtime vs. Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rZxy.png)

I need the 5000<sup>th</sup> input to be less than a 12-second run-time.  The current code takes about 45 seconds.

Comment: you can use the pow function to compute powers modulo 10 to speed up your calculations. eg `pow(n, 2, 10)` will return the last digit of n squared

Comment: @DanielGee Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately no change in runtime, but did condense the code.

Comment: This question is far more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Particularly in this case using `str` is time intensive. You can rewrite it using logical operation. But if you really want speed, write it by C programming language. It may speed up 100 times or more.

Comment: That's not really the problem, these numbers are becoming astronomically big fast (i.e. nr 24 is 9918212890625, which you're not going to be able to bruteforce, including with C). You need a better algorithm, [relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192720/automorphic-numbers)

Comment: @ti7 I disagree; SO is fine for algorithm discussion; that's why we have a separate tag for that alone.

Answer (score 0):

- Use meaningful variable names; alphabet soup is hard to read.
- Do your math in integers, not converting to/from strings.  Since you start with a 1-digit number, you *know* the string length; keep the proper power of 10.  Instead of string concatenation and conversion to integer, just make the number directly.

Code

```
for f in range(1, n//2):
  ten_power = next_power    # Keep track of length in digits
  next_power *= 10

  # "old5" is the previous automorphic number ending in 5
  for digit in range(9, 0, -1):
      new5 = old5 + digit * ten_power
      new5sq = new5*new5
      if new5sq % next_power == new5:
          # you found the number
          old5 = new5
          break
```

Can you work these things into your existing code?  Note that the outer `for` loop has a different control; find *both* the 5 and 6 numbers for `n//2` times.  The only time you care about the smaller one is on the final iteration for odd `n`.

This found `green(5000)` in 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It'll just take few microsecs to work
Code

```
n=int(input('Enter any no.'))
temp=n
div=1
while temp>=1:
    temp=temp//10
    div=div*10
x=n**2
y=x%div
if n==y:
    print(' Automorphic')
else:
    print(' Not Automorphic')
```

Sweet n simple!